# Which solver pulp decided to use?

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

When we write

```
prob.solve()
```

program decides automatically which method to use. Is it possible to find out, which method PULP decided to use in my problem?

Comment: [How to configure a solver in PuLP](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/guides/how_to_configure_solvers.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encourage you to read pulp's [docs](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/main/includeme.html#examples). Or the project README: https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/

> See the examples directory for examples.
>
> PuLP requires Python 2.7 or Python >= 3.4.
>
> The examples use the default solver (CBC). To use other solvers they must be available (installed and accessible). For more information on how to do that, see the guide on configuring solvers.